# Header Cart information will change to default when click on addtocart button in opencart

Tags: ajax, opencart

> I have change Header cart in formation like remove cart icon and add
>   HTML tag on it.

```
language/english/common/cart.php
$_['text_items']     = '<p>Mycart</p><span><em>%s</em> item(s) - %s</span>';

common/cart.tpl
  <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-loading-text="<?php echo $text_loading; ?>" class="btn btn-inverse btn-block btn-lg dropdown-toggle"><!-- <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>  --><span id="cart-total"><?php echo $text_items; ?></span></button>
```

> It work fine but when i click on addtocart button it load using Ajax
>   and the previous modified cart tags reset to default. when refresh it
>   again work. any one knew about this.

Answer (score 1):

> It is happened due to when we click on addtocart button on product
>   detial page it will call call function on click event and load
>   checkout/cart using ajax so we need to make synchronize common/cart
>   information and chekout/cart infourmation
>   I solve the issues as
>   follows:
>
> in product.tpl or other page where you add addtocart
>
> inside

```
$('#button-cart').on('click', function() {
```

> we will find

```
if (json['success']) {
                $('.breadcrumb').after('<div class="alert alert-success">' + json['success'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');

                $('#cart > button').html('<!--<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>--> ' + json['total']);//here you can get the cart icon  and comment out he icon code

                $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');

                $('#cart > ul').load('index.php?route=common/cart/info ul li');
            }
```

> for add other tag inside cart info modify on
>   language/english/checkout/cart.php

```
$_['text_items']               = '<p>Mycart</p><span><em>%s</em> item(s) - %s</span>';
```

> and it work for me